# PHP Phalcon Routing with file extension

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

In my PHP Phalcon 3 Application I have a custom route:

```
$router->add("/{chapter}/{name}.{type:[a-z]+}", array(
        "controller" => 'images',
        "action" => 'getFile',
    ));
```

I test the application local with PHP Builtin Server, other routes are working regulary.
If i test the route above:
http://localhost:8000/XYZ/test.jpg
I always get a 404. 
But in regards to the documentation it should work: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html

Do you have any idea whats wrong?

This is my .htrouter for the php built in server:

```
<?php

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $_GET['_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
return false;
```

Comment: And you sure it's even hitting phalcon application ?

Comment: No i think the 404 comes from the built in server. 
But all other routes are handled by the application also if I change the file extension from .jpg to _jpg

Comment: Well can't you just use nginx or apache ? Don't know why it's not routing with built-in php server.

Comment: You should be aware that nothing better serves static content than nginx or at least any web server

Comment: @Juri I'm using Nginx for Production but it would be easier for me if I could use the PHP Built in Server for development

Comment: @stamster I'm using Nginx for Production, the route is for image reseizing. For Development it would be easier if I could use the PHP Built in Server

Comment: What's a problem with downloading nginx and setting it ? It's like 5 minutes and no problem.