# PHP buit in server error

Tags: php, phalcon, php-builtin-server

For local development I'm using the php built in server.
Everythig works finde so far, but if in a url is a point or a file suffix the built in server returns a 404 even before it hitting my application

Im using the phalcon framework

This is my .htrouter.php:

```
<?php

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
   $_GET['_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

return false;
```

Comment: That's why I like apache more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Phalcon Routing with file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722558/php-phalcon-routing-with-file-extension)

Comment: have a look here: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.file-exists.php#75064